# how to use $addToSet and $inc value of the set item in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a collection of documents with an embedded array:

```
 {
   name: 'doc1',
   events: []
 },
 {
   name: 'doc1',
   events: [{eventName: 'e1', times: 10}, {eventName: 'e2', times: 1}]
 }
```

How can I add an event to the embedded array and increment the 'times' value? I don't want to have a duplicate event name in the events array.

---

Update:
I changed my model to make queries simpler. instead of

```
 events: [{eventName: 'e1', times: 10}, {eventName: 'e2', times: 1}]
```

the model is:

```
events: { e1: 10, e2: 1}
```

Now it's much easier to update documents with a simple query. **However still curious if anyone comes up with a simple and readable query without changing the data model.**

```
 .events.updateOne({name: 'doc1'}, { $inc: {events.e1: 1}});
```

Comment: Increment all `times` values?

Comment: assue there is a new event 'e2' for doc1 then I expect and update that results -> {
   name: 'doc1',
   events: [{eventName: 'e1', times: 10}, {eventName: 'e2', times: 2}]
 }

Comment: Problem with `$addToSet` is, the element is `{eventName: 'e2', times: 1}` and not `{eventName: 'e2'}` which makes it (I would assume) impossible to use simple `$addToSet`

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
var newEvent = "e2"
db.collection.aggregate([
   {
      $set: {
         events: {
            $cond: {
               if: { $in: [newEvent, "$events.eventName"] },
               then: {
                  $map: {
                     input: "$events",
                     as: "event",
                     in: { $mergeObjects: ["$$event", { times: { $add: ["$$event.times", 1] } }] }
                  }
               },
               else: { $concatArrays: ["$events", [{ eventName: newEvent, "times": 0 }]] },
            }
         }
      }
   }
])
```

Comment: Thanks, it works but is there any better way? I changed my model instead to make it simpler, I've updated the question. is that really necessary to user aggregate framework?

Comment: Now you create a completely new question which makes any existing answer invalid, please don't do that. Open a new question for changed data model. And yes, I think you cannot avoid aggregation framework, the updated is even more complex and certainly requires aggregation.

Comment: The question is still the same, update is my workaround to make query simpler, and no it doesn't need aggregation framework, I updated with sample query

Comment: Yes, using `{ $inc: {events.times: 1}}` increments `events.times`. However it updates **every** element and it completely ignores your requirement "I don't want to have a duplicate event name in the events array." Your "simplified" data model with dynamic field name is much more complex (unless the events are fix) and cannot be done without aggregation pipeline.

Comment: sorry I missed the e1, updated the query

Comment: It's in production running like this without aggregation

Comment: It works if the field names are static. Otherwise you either need an aggregation pipeline or you need to compose update command dynamically. What is your aversion against aggregation pipeline?

Comment: const updateQuers  = {};
updateQuery['events.e5'] = 1;
.events.updateOne({name: 'doc1'}, { $inc: updateQuery});
this is how you handle dynamic fields

Comment: Thanks for your answer by the way, I'm still looking to know how to do it without changing model, and your answer is working fine, just want to know what are the other ways

Comment: Having dynamic field names is usually a poor design, because then you will heavily use `$arrayToObject` and `$objectToArray`